# Error: _Atomic cannot be applied to qualified type 'NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *__strong'

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos

I am getting an error during compilation of a class member variable. This
was compiling fine before, the change I made is to add "std::atomic" to do an atomic_compare_exchange on it in a member method

```
std::atomic<dispatch_source_t> msource;
```

Is dispatch_source_t can't be made atomic?

Is there any way I could make it to compile? Please help!

Error:

```
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:963:37: error: _Atomic cannot be applied to qualified type 'NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *__strong' 
  _LIBCPP_DISABLE_EXTENSION_WARNING _Atomic(_Tp) __a_value;
                                    ^

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:1501:35: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *>' requested here
struct __cxx_atomic_impl : public _Base {
                                  ^

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:1616:36: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__cxx_atomic_impl<NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *>' requested here
    mutable __cxx_atomic_impl<_Tp> __a_;
                                   ^

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:1848:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__atomic_base<NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *, false>' requested here
    : public __atomic_base<_Tp*>
             ^

note: in instantiation of template class 'std::atomic<NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *>' requested here
    std::atomic<dispatch_source_t> msource;
                                   ^
```

Comment: This is not objective-c , I suppose c++ ?

Comment: Thanks! Added C++ now.  dispatch_source_t is apple's https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_source_t

Comment: `std::atomic<T>` requires that `T` is trivially copyable which I don't think is the case for automatically reference counted objects such as `dispatch_source_t`.